# Is it possible to detect the resume-able links via QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: qt, network-programming

Suppose i wish to pause the download, and start it again. Can we know before hand whether the link is resume-able. I mean is this info available with the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wand to know that before starting the download, you can send a HEAD request and check if the field "Accept-Ranges: bytes" is present in the header.

`QNetworkAccessManager` does contain some code to handle resuming when the network session is interrupted, but unfortunately it is not part of the public API.

Comment: I've written an example app that does this and also handles pause/resume, restarting after unexpected shutdowns and pipelining:
https://github.com/parsley72/QtDownloadManager