# Is it possible to detect a resumable FTP link via QNetworkAccessManager?

Tags: qt, ftp, network-programming

I know how to detect and resume downloads from an HTTP server (see [Is it possible to detect the resume-able links via QNetworkAccessManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469072/is-it-possible-to-detect-the-resume-able-links-via-qnetworkaccessmanager) and my example code at https://github.com/parsley72/QtDownloadManager) but how do I do the same from an FTP server?

Comment: I've added my solution to my example code: https://github.com/parsley72/QtDownloadManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is not, QNetworkAccessManager has minimal support for FTP and we cant use commands other than 'get'. You can certainly detect resumable link if you use QFTP (deprecated in Qt 5.0 and above).

I hope they add support for commands for other than 'Get' in QNetworkAccessManager so that there is no need of using QFTP. When that happens we can use "REST" command to verify whether link is resumable or not.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example of using QFtp for detecting and using resume?

Comment: @parsley72 This might help you in implementing same in QFtp http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8667/FTP-Client-Class as concepts remain same it revolves around "REST" command